# Could someone explain what the ?'s do in mySQL?

Tags: php, sql

**I have this mySQL command.  What do the ?'s represent?**  It's being used in a php model.

```
UPDATE posts SET title=?,content=?,categoryID=?,date=? WHERE pID = ?
```

Comment: ...I wish there were rep associated with identifying duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "prepared statements".  The syntax is applicable beyond PHP and beyond mySQL.  Here is the relevant documentation:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Prepared statements are a VERY useful thing, and should arguably be used whenever possible with *all* SQL queries on *all* web pages.

Here is a good article explaining one reason why: among other things, prepared statements help mitigate SQL Injection attacks:

- http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-php-using-prepared-statements

Answer (score 1):

The question mark (`?`) is used to represent variables - it also acts as a placeholder using which you can insert a value for the corresponding column.

From the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> The SQL statement can contain zero or more named (:name) or **question
>   mark (?)** parameter markers for which real values will be substituted
>   when the statement is executed. You cannot use both named and question
>   mark parameter markers within the same SQL statement; pick one or the
>   other parameter style. **Use these parameters to bind any user-input, do
>   not include the user-input directly in the query**.